# How i can create custom user and role with ASP.NET Core identity v preview 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identity, asp.net-core-identity

When i'm creating migrates, i get error, something like this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityRole' because this type is not included in the model for the context.

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'UserApp' because this type is not included in the model for the context.
```

Yeah, i don't have this columns in my context, but in previus version, it`s working without that.
My code is:

```
public class UserApp: IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public string Country { get; set; } 

    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}
```

and Context class:

```
public class ApplicationContext:DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext()
    {

    }

    //public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {

    }
```

with some dbset. In startup class, i have :

```
services.AddIdentity<UserApp, IdentityRole>(o =>
{
    o.Password.RequireDigit = false;

    o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;

    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;

    o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
})
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

What's wrong? And really in this version i must add to my context User's and Role's property?

Comment: `ApplicationContext:DbContext`? That class is completely empty. That should be `ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext`...

Comment: @camilo-terevinto,Yeah, i'm forget about that, but it's nothing change in this situation. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is your `ApplicationContext` is inheriting `DbContext` instead of `IdentityDbContext`. So your `ApplicationContext` should be as follows:

```
public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<UserApp, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    }
}
```